# Why determinant appear for constant term of equation of line?

Tags: geometry

The equation of line which is on (a,b),(c,d) is $(b-d)x-(a-c)y+ad-bc=0$.

The constant term, $ad-bc$, is same to the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}$.

Is this just coincidence or some relationship exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start from the useful formula of the distance from a point $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$ to a line (L) with equation $ux+wy+w=0$ which is

$$d(P_0,(L))=\dfrac{|ux_0+vy_0+w|}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$$

(see [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)). In the case at hand, taking moreover $P_0=O$ (the origin), we have

$$d(O,(L))=\dfrac{|ad-bc|}{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}\tag{1}$$

If we denote  $A=(a,b)$ and $B=(c,d)$, and $H$ the orthogonal projection of $O$ onto line $AB$, relationship will become :

$$OH \ \ = \ \ \dfrac{2 \ \text{area of triangle} \ OAB}{AB}$$
i.e. 
$$\text{area of triangle} \ OAB \ \ = \ \ \frac12 AB . OH$$

which is a classical triangle relationship.

Were you familiar with the fact that the determinant of 2 vectors is the
area of the parallelogram generated by these two vectors, therefore twice the area of the generated triangle ?

Remark : we could have uses another interpretation of the (absolute value of) the determinant is the norm of their cross product which is:

$$|\det(\vec{OA},\vec{OB})| \ = \ \|\vec{OA} \times \vec{OB}\| \ = \ OA.OB \sin \alpha$$

[image]

Comment: I just added a little picture.

Answer (score 0):

If the line equation is $$px+qy=r,$$

we have to solve the system of two equations in three unknowns

$$\begin{cases}pa+qb=r,\\pc+qd=r.\end{cases}$$

If we assume $r$ to be known, the solution in $p,q$ is, by Cramer,

$$p=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}r&b\\r&d\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}}=r\frac{d-b}{\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}},
\\
q=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}a&r\\c&r\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}}=r\frac{a-c}{\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}}.$$

Then a nice choice is $$r=\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix},$$ leading to

$$p=d-b,\\q=a-c,\\r=ad-bc.$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line is of the form $l_1 x + l_2 y = \alpha$.

Note that one can multiply the $l_k, \alpha$ by any non zero constant and one gets the same
line.

Presumably we can presume that the two points are distinct.

If $(a,b), (c,d)$ are on the line then we can write 
$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} l_1 \\ l_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}$.

Since $(\det A)I = (\operatorname{adj}A )A$, the above gives
$(ad-bc) \begin{bmatrix} l_1 \\ l_2 \end{bmatrix} = \alpha \begin{bmatrix} d-b \\ a-c \end{bmatrix}$.

If $ab-dc \neq 0$, we can choose $\alpha = ad-bc$ to get the formula in the question.

If $ab-dc = 0$ then the two points are linearly dependent which in the plane means that one is a multiple of the other (since they are not the same).
In this case we must have $\alpha = 0$, and it is easy to check that
$\begin{bmatrix} l_1 \\ l_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} d-b \\ a-c \end{bmatrix}$
is a solution and the formula in the question still works.